# Using EWS, CcRecipients and DisplayCc don't match

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get the list of CC email addresses using EWS. I can see there is a value in DisplayCc, but CcRecipients is empty. (Please refer to the link image to see the values.) What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim eItem As EmailMessage = DirectCast(mItem, EmailMessage)
Dim eas As String = eItem.DisplayCc
Dim accRecipients As EmailAddressCollection = eItem.CcRecipients
For Each eccrecipient In accRecipients
    Dim ea As String = eccrecipient.ToString
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a DUH! All I needed to do was LOAD the email message before trying to get the eItem.CcRecipients. Now my code works as expected.

```
Dim eItem As EmailMessage = DirectCast(mItem, EmailMessage)
**eItem.load**
Dim eas As String = eItem.DisplayCc
Dim accRecipients As EmailAddressCollection = eItem.CcRecipients
For Each eccrecipient In accRecipients
    Dim ea As String = eccrecipient.ToString
Next
```